# Fastest way to put a smaller n-dimensional array in a bigger one (2d graphical analogy: paint rectangle on canvas)

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, logic

Say I have this 10x5 array:

```
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
```

and this 1x2 array:

```
AB
CD
EF
```

Now I want to write the second array into the bigger one at position 1/2 (X-pos/Y-pos), deleting all old values (my example is zero based & inclusive). The result would be:

```
..........
..........
.AB.......
.CD.......
.EF.......
```

There might be multiple sub arrays with a known overwrite hierarchy, the arrays might have more than 3 dimensions and the arrays contain complex objects.

Is there a best practice to do this in C#?
Is there language agnostic solution?

Comment: How big are we talking here? In general, I think that you can really only avoid bounds checking to improve performance. Copying one row at a time could be faster using eg. `memcpy`, but I don't believe that's worth it until you're copying at least hundreds of bytes per line (and possibly, much more than that). Also, not sure about the performance, but perhaps actually using drawing functions might be the fastest way, if you can avoid conversions - ie. treat both byte arrays as 8-bit bitmaps and use masking to paint one in the other. In any case, experiments are the way to go. Try and profile.

Comment: Shouldn't get bigger than 2000x2000x2000x... . The solutions that come up in my head scream "WE ARE INEFFICIENT SLOW HACKS SOMEONE MUST HAVE A BETTER SOLUTION FOR THIS ALREADY."

Comment: Well, you could try writing everything in `unsafe` or using `memcpy` and similars - you can then see if it is actually better in practice, and implement it in your core code, knowing of the actual gains you're going to get. It used to be that doing a copy using a specialized blitter hardware was much faster, but CPUs are really really fast nowadays. The only improvement I could think of is using DMA to copy rows one at a time - I think `Buffer.BlockCopy` or `memcpy` do precisely that. In a naive implementation I think your best bet is to avoid bounds checking. Try and profile :))

Answer (score 0):

Okay, `Buffer.BlockCopy` is significantly faster than copying data byte-by-byte, even after you eliminate bounds checking. Interestingly, it seems that `Buffer.BlockCopy` does in fact work on 2D arrays :)

So you might want to try something like this:

```
byte[,] source = new byte[1000, 100];
byte[,] dest = new byte[2048, 2048];

int offsetX = 100;
int offsetY = 20;

int width = source.GetLength(0);
int height = source.GetLength(1);

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
  Buffer.BlockCopy
  (
    source, y * height, 
    dest, offsetX + dest.GetLength(1) * (y + offsetY), 
    width
  );
}
```

Basically, assuming that the array is a byte array with X as the first index, and Y as the second, I go one row at a time, blitting the whole row from source to dest at once.

It seems much much faster than simply copying one byte at a time, so I assume that it does actually use DMA instead of using the CPU to copy the bytes.

Do note that this will only be faster if the rows are long enough. If you're copying a single column, it will probably be slower than just copying byte by byte. If you find yourself copying columns more often than rows (ie. `width` is usually less than `height`), you might want to think about inverting the coordinates, ie. swapping X and Y.